# Mains earth and op amp ground

Tags: power-supply, operational-amplifier, ground

I was trying to power a transimpedance amplifier built with an op amp on a protoboard.

I only had a power supply that looked like the first image below (no COM, which I would have connected to GND of the op amp).

The answers I got for my initial question posted on this website were really good and perfectly explained what I was supposed to do. (I initially asked questions about different kinds of power supplies)

I made a mistake of connecting the mains earth of the power supply (circled in the first image below) to the + pin of the op-amp, where GND (COM of a power supply) was supposed to go.  I understand why I was not supposed to do it. The mains earth is ill-defined since it is disconnected from both positive and negative voltage outputs of the power supply.

It seems I broke my op amp when I connected the mains earth to + pin of the op amp where GND (so COM) was supposed to go. I see that I was not supposed to do it.

My question is how did I break the op amp by connecting the mains earth to the + pin of the op amp?

[image]
[image]

Comment: And your question is?

Comment: What was IN- of the op-amp connected to?

Comment: That is a single supply.  you will have to create a "virtual ground" midway between the supply terminals to act as a circuit ground for your op-amp circuit.  You should not have any connection to the Mains Ground (the green post on the supply).

Comment: @laptop2d Thank you for the response.  My question is how I broke the op-amp by connecting the mains earth to the + pin of the op amp.

Comment: @ThePhoton it was connected to some current from my other circuit, which I confirmed works and when I properly hooked up the op-amp with its + pin connected to COM of the power supply unit that has COM, everything worked well.

Comment: @Black: What exactly are you trying to build? Does it need a single power (COM and V+) supply or a dual power supply (V- COM V+)?

Comment: @Transistor I had a perfectly good working transimpedance amplifier on a protoboard powered by a dual power supply  (V- COM V+).  I didn't know that there were different kinds of power supply units and ended up messing up the op-amp of the transimpedance amplifier with a single power supply unit with remote sense inputs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fYbiBk.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1. What you've done.*

[image]

*Figure 2. What you're not accounting for.*

The power supply has capacitive coupling between the high-voltage side of the transformer and the low-voltage side. This occurs through the transformer capacitance and the deliberate capacitance circled in Figure 2. The effect of this is that the PSU output has a weak alternating voltage on it. You might be able to read this with a digital multimeter between one of the terminals and the mains earth.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fXIbZw.png)</sup>

Your op-amp has a very high input impedance and is very sensitive to over-voltage. Most likely is that the capacitively coupled voltage exceeded the maximum allowable input to the op-amp.